# Can I disable specific "Host Commands" in Icinga's (1.14) web interface?

Tags: icinga

I have web users (NOC workers) who are (against our instructions) enabling active checks on my Icinga 1 server. This causes the checked hosts to appear to be down when they are not, etc.

I'd like to disable the "Enable active checks of this host" link but I can't see how to do this. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only [icinga-web](https://github.com/Icinga/icinga-web) (1) can do that.

There is a permission setting for "critical commands" in the user/group settings.

Also you can edit the [command definitions](https://github.com/Icinga/icinga-web/tree/master/app/modules/Api/config/commands).

Just comment them out, or set `<ic:isSimple>true</ic:isSimple>`.

Comment: Sadly, those xml files do not exist in my ancient Icinga 1.14 install.

Comment: Then you are using Icinga Classic UI, please have a look on Icinga 2 and Icinga web 2.